# Current directory gets set to the Outlook application's directory in when opened through Windows application

Tags: c#, outlook

The current directory variable in my application gets set to Outlook application's directory when I open it using MAPI Server method through my Windows application. I want to know how to reset the current directory to my application's directory.

Comment: You will need to show some code to explain more clearly how you are using it, opening it7what etc.

Comment: I am writing the code to open the Outlook popup from a class.

MAPI mapi = new MAPI();
mapi.AddAttachment(filepath + "\\" + filename);
mapi.SendMailPopup("PDF Report", "");

Then in another class, I write all the stuff related to Mail Composer.

Comment: Please edit your questions with the relevant code. It makes it much more confusing to read them in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAPI system used by both Outlook and the standalone version of MAPI are known to change the current directory. There is nothing you can do. Your app should not depend on relative paths, and you can always retrieve the current directory and reset it back as necessary.